# Not able to update database

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I am  not able to update one field. Please Suggest me what is the wrong thing in my code.

```
Code:

- (int) updateTaskDoneDate:(double)donedate ontaskid:(int)taskId
{
    sqlite3 *database;
    @try {
        if (sqlite3_open([self.databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSString *sql_str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update task set donedate='%f' where taskid=%d ", donedate ,taskId];
            NSLog(@"sql str: %@",sql_str);
            const char *sql = [sql_str UTF8String];

            sqlite3_stmt *statement;
            statement = [self PrepareStatement:sql];

            NSDate *myDate;
            myDate=[NSDate date];

            int a1 = sqlite3_bind_double(statement, 1, [myDate timeIntervalSince1970]);
            int a2 = sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 2, taskId);
            NSLog(@"a1a2 %d, %d", a1, a2);
            if (statement)
            {
                if (a1 != SQLITE_OK ||  a2 != SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                    return 0;
                }
                sqlite3_step(statement);
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception){
        [self showException:exception];
    }
    @finally {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I presume your `databasePath` is in your `Documents` folder, and not the bundle? You cannot update databases that are in the bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. You're using `sqlite3_bind_xxx` (which is good, much better than building the SQL with `stringWithFormat`), but you don't have any `?` placeholders in your SQL. Your SQL should presumably be:

   ```
   NSString *sql_str = @"update task set donedate=? where taskid=?";
   ```

   You don't need the `stringWithFormat` call, because you're binding your variables. You also don't need the quotes around your double value, either.
2. You're not showing the prepare statement, but if it fails, are you logging `sqlite3_errmsg`?
3. Likewise on your bind statements, if they're not `SQLITE_OK`, you're not logging `sqlite3_errmsg`.
4. Your `sqlite3_step` isn't checking its return code at all, much less logging `sqlite3_errmsg` if it's not `SQLITE_DONE`.

Bottom line, you must bind with `?` placeholders and you're flying blind because you're not logging `sqlite3_errmsg` on failures.

Comment: Is it compulsory to add prepare statement?

Comment: @Aaaaa If you're going to bind variables, yes, you prepare before you bind and step, and finalize when done. If you're not binding any variables, you can do `sqlite3_exec` which encapsulates preparing, a single step call, and finalizing. But, yes, if you're going to use a statement that you're going to bind, step, etc., you must prepare.

Comment: @Aaaaa I presumed your `PrepareStatement` was doing the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` call...

Comment: Thank you so much, for your help and for helpful knowledge.